Toon shader broken in Eevee 4.2
System Information
Operating system: Windows-11 64 Bits
Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 3070. Pilote version : 560.70
Blender Version: Blender 4.2 LTS

Hi guys! The new Eevee version is out and I just discovered that the toon shaders for my character have now completely broken shadows. I tried to fix that, in vain.
Have you any ideas? Is there a way to go back to the old shading system in Eevee 4.2?




Looks like enabling Subsurface Scattering causes the bug. So disable it to fix it if it is not so important... The Issue should be reported as a bug.

Well, it is a bug, I have reported it: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/124910
But it causes by Subsurface scattering, that doesn't work in 4.1. So you can just disable it by setting Subsurface weight to 0:


Thanks, you saved me!
